# Cassandra multi AZ seeds

Tags: cassandra

We are planning an AWS cluster with 6 nodes with 2 nodes in 3 availability zones all in the same region.
AZ1a - node1 and node2
AZ1b - node3 and node4
AZ1c - node5 and node6

What is recommended for the seeds?  Should it be node1, node3, and node5 so there is a seed in each AZ?

Regards.

Comment: Yes, having 1 seed node per AZ is good idea. It also aids during nodes bootstrapping in corresponding AZ.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Regards.